# Socket Connection getting closed after serving client in perl

Tags: perl, sockets

i was trying to create a tcp socket server using perl. I was succesfully able to create a server which listens in particular port. But after serving one client request, Socket server is getting closed. The server is not listening for more than one client request.

```
while (accept(Client, Server)) {
    # do something with new Client connection
    if ($kidpid = fork) {
            close Client;         # parent closes unused handle
            #next REQUEST;
            next REQUEST if $!{EINTR};
    }
    print "$kidpid\n";
    defined($kidpid)   or die "cannot fork: $!" ;

    close Server;             # child closes unused handle

    select(Client);           
    $| = 1;                  ]
    select (STDOUT);

    # per-connection child code does I/O with Client handle
    $input = <Client>;
    print Client "output11\n";  # or STDOUT, same thing

    open(STDIN, "<<&Client")    or die "can't dup client: $!";
    open(STDOUT, ">&Client")    or die "can't dup client: $!";
    open(STDERR, ">&Client")    or die "can't dup client: $!";


    print "finished\n";    

    close Client;
        exit;
}
```

I am unable to find the issue in the above code. Could some one please help me on this?

Comment: The code you're showing is a syntax error (at least b/c of the stray, unmatched `]`) and possibly a runtime error (missing REQUEST label).  Can you turn this into the [smallest code that shows the behavior in question](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find working example of INET/TCP socket server in perlipc(1) man page. I prefer using IO::Socket standard as described [here](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.0/pod/perlipc.pod#TCP_Servers_with_IO%3a%3aSocket). If you don't want to use the IO::Socket module, you have working example [here](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.0/pod/perlipc.pod#Internet_TCP_Clients_and_Servers).

Server sample code from this manual:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
 use IO::Socket;
 use Net::hostent;      # for OOish version of gethostbyaddr

 $PORT = 9000;          # pick something not in use

 $server = IO::Socket::INET->new( Proto     => "tcp",
                                  LocalPort => $PORT,
                                  Listen    => SOMAXCONN,
                                  Reuse     => 1);

 die "can't setup server" unless $server;
 print "[Server $0 accepting clients]\n";

 while ($client = $server->accept()) {
   $client->autoflush(1);
   print $client "Welcome to $0; type help for command list.\n";
   $hostinfo = gethostbyaddr($client->peeraddr);
   printf "[Connect from %s]\n", $hostinfo ? $hostinfo->name : $client->peerhost;
   print $client "Command? ";
   while ( <$client>) {
     next unless /\S/;       # blank line
     if    (/quit|exit/i)    { last                                      }
     elsif (/date|time/i)    { printf $client "%s\n", scalar localtime() }
     elsif (/who/i )         { print  $client `who 2>&1`                 }
     elsif (/cookie/i )      { print  $client `/usr/games/fortune 2>&1`  }
     elsif (/motd/i )        { print  $client `cat /etc/motd 2>&1`       }
     else {
       print $client "Commands: quit date who cookie motd\n";
     }
   } continue {
      print $client "Command? ";
   }
   close $client;
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks pzn. your code helps me. I will try to include child process to cater my requirement. Thanks